# Only include scripts from used plugins in page

Tags: javascript, html, css, impresspages

Is it possible to only include the scripts etc. that are actually used on the site/page in the HTML output shown to the world?

Loading the JS and CSS files for all installed plugins and the admin interface (like the following), slows down the page a lot:

```
var ip = {"baseUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/ImpressPages\/","safeMode":false,"languageId":1...
```

Thanks
Morten

Comment: yes.... it is possible

Comment: Just include only what you need, why would you include unneeded scripts ?

Comment: @singe31 If you look at the source of a theme that use ipHead() and ipJs() it will include all scripts and code used for the editor + for all installed widgets (even it they are not used)..

Comment: Then include the scripts manually on the pages that you think are too slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each plugin decides what assets should be included on each page load. Despite that you can create your own plugin that follows your own logic and removes some assets before page is rendered (I'd use `ipBeforeController` event for that). `_1` means low priority to make sure your script is the last in a row.

```
class Event
{
    public static function ipBeforeController_1()
    {
        // Get all added JavaScript files
        $allJs = \Ip\ServiceLocator::pageAssets()->getJavascript();

        // ... your logic ...

        // Remove
        \Ip\ServiceLocator::pageAssets()->removeJavascript($fileName);
    }
}
```